# Keep value converter out of view-model

Tags: knockout.js

In KO docs there is an example of value converter using **computed observables**:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html#example-3-a-value-converter

However, I would like an approach where the value converter is outside the view-model, like how `IValueConverter` works is in Windows,  the view-model is not aware in any way about the converter.

I'm thinking about a feature which could allow me to write something like this:

```
data-bind="converter : { source: myBindingObject, converter: app.myConverter }"
```

and converter is an object with a read/write function:

```
app.myConverter = {
    convert: function (value, parameter) {

    },
    convertFrom: function (value, parameter) {

    }
};
```

Maybe there is a way already I'm not aware of.

For example, what I'm describing sounds similar to a KO extender, but it requires the property in the view-model code to use `.extend(extender)` which like I said, it is not what I want

Answer (score 1):

Woa, back up a second. You ask a very broad question, where it's hard to see the practical application / where we are missing actual context. Are you sure this isn't an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Perhaps you're looking for classical or prototypal inheritance to DRY up your view models, and when you've done so it no longer feels like a requirement to get this out of your view models.

In other words: let us know *why* you need this, and give us a practical problem / scenario / repro. This will make it a lot easier for us to help you.

In any case, there is only one relevant default Knockout construct that I know of that answers the direct question you ask: [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). They also have the equivalent of read and write, but then aimed at DOM action (reading view models into the DOM, and vice versa). They are unobtrusive to your view model, instead specified in the DOM.